# Основной ответ от гугла Python

Tags: python, google-search

На вопросы "Столица россии" или "сколько дней в неделе" гугл выдает ответы еще в поисковой строке.

[image: Пример]

Как можно получать этот ответ не переходя на сайты и не открывая окно браузера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pydash
import requests
import json
import html
import re

req_text = input()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'q': req_text,
    'client': 'psy-ab',
    'gs_ri': 'gws-wiz',
}

res = requests.get("https://www.google.com/complete/search", params=params, headers=headers)

result = html.unescape(re.findall(r"\[.*\]", res.text).pop())
result_json = json.loads(result)

print(pydash.get(result_json, '0.0.-1.ansa.l.-1.il.t.0.t'))
```

```
from toolz import get_in, pluck
import requests
import json
import html
import re

req_text = input()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'part': req_text,
    'srv': 'morda_ru_desktop',
    'fact': '1',
    'v': '4'
}

res = requests.get("https://yandex.ru/suggest/suggest-ya.cgi", params=params, headers=headers)
result_json = json.loads(res.text)
facts_only = filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'fact', result_json[1])

print(list(map(lambda list: list[1] + ": " + list[2], facts_only)))
```

Comment: Можно делать также с Яндексом? Он все же больше ответов дает(Например Сколько дней в неделе, гугл не отвечает, яндекс же дает ответ)

Comment: Можно и с яндексом так же сделать)

Comment: Расскажите принцип, дальше сам додумаю

Comment: @ДаниилКустов, вот так можно, обновил

Comment: Страшна) Ладно, буду разбираться :). Кстати откуда взяты ссылки(https://www.google.com/complete/search) и (https://yandex.ru/suggest/suggest-ya.cgi)

Comment: Вкладка `network` в `Chrome dev tools`.

Comment: Премного благодарен! Удачи вам

Comment: Можете попробовать набрать "сколько лет", там будет множество разных ответов.

Comment: Попробуйте набрать сколько лет в веке, или сколько годов в году.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108566/discussion-between---and--).